# Finding dollar sign with strpos

Tags: php

So I'm trying to find several special characters, such as {, $ in a string returned by DOM element

When I run

```
if(strpos("$", $u) === FALSE AND strpos("{", $u) === FALSE AND $u != "#") {
echo "Attempting {$u} ecoded: ".urlencode($u)."<br/>";
return true;
}
```

However when I run it, it prints out:

```
Attempting register.php ecoded: register.php
Attempting {$url} ecoded: %7B%24url%7D
Attempting $authUrl ecoded: %24authUrl
Attempting services.php ecoded: services.php
```

So I tried using HEX values and ASCII but still had no luck!

Comment: If you're looking for the character try: `if(strpos("$", $u) !== FALSE AND strpos("{", $u) !== FALSE AND $u != "#")`

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Yes, what is the question here.

Comment: Why is it not working.. and if I said !== then I'd be saying if the character IS there, not if it's not there

Comment: @SauliusAntanavicius Just because I think you might have missed my answer in the flurry of edits/comments I'll repeat myself here. I'm pretty sure you have a simple error: your arguments to strpos are in the wrong order.

Comment: How can they be in wrong order?

Comment: Ah, had the arguments in the wrong order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've reversed the arguments for strpos.

`int strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )`

Just swap them around, and it should work as intended.

Comment: Oh god! Can't believe I made that mistake.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$ is a special character within a double quoted string. You need to escape it with a backslash or use single quotes instead.

```
if(strpos("\$", $u) === FALSE AND strpos("{", $u) === FALSE AND $u != "#") {
```

or:

```
if(strpos('$', $u) === FALSE AND strpos("{", $u) === FALSE AND $u != "#") {
```

Comment: As pointed out by ben, I had the arguments in the wrong order.. Silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

```
$u = 'services.php';

if (preg_match('/[\#\$\{\}]/is', $u))
        echo "Attempting {$u} echoed: ".urlencode($u);
```

will echo nothing.